# ogr2ogr MVT Append

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am creating a MVT (Mapbox Vector Tile) MBTile for various layers from my PostGIS database but I cannot seem to get ogr2ogr to append to an existing MBTile.

I am currently using the following command to export

`ogr2ogr -progress -gt 65000 -f MVT Water.mbtiles PG:"database connection" -dsco MINZOOM=6 -dsco MAXZOOM=8 -dsco NAME=water -sql "SELECT geom FROM water"`

I then want to append different data to the same MBTile but at different zoom levels so my next export command is

`ogr2ogr -append -progress -gt 65000 -f MVT Water.mbtiles PG:"database connection" -dsco MINZOOM=9 -dsco MAXZOOM=12 -dsco NAME=water -sql "SELECT geom FROM water2"`

I can error message saying 'Unable to open existing data source'

Can anyone help advise me on how I can do this?

Comment: Just a guess but try to add -update.

Comment: Tried append and update individually and then both at the same time, unfortunately same error as above

Comment: I would send mail to gdal-dev mailing linst and ask if MVT driver supports append.